# TUI (Toast UI) Calendar API not working as expected.

Tags: javascript, calendar, ui-calendar

I have started working on one project and facing some issue. while looking at calendar apps I found this one:

https://github.com/nhnent/tui.calendar#easy-to-use-dragging-and-resizing-a-schedule

This seems to be best package for my app it has all the functionality and UI that I need for my project. Image is attached below

[image]

But Interestingly when I setup this project on my local instance by copying code from this repo and include cdn links to html head tag, it shows me below Interface which is very simple and miss almost all the functionality, no pop up appears on clicking slots (time) as well.

[image]

My Question is Am I doing anything wrong? I have just included CDN links to my app and copied code. it should work but I don't know the reason why it is not working like that.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version (1.7.0) has some dependencies, that you have to include.

[tui-code-snippet](https://github.com/nhnent/tui.code-snippet) >= 1.4.0

[tui-date-picker](https://github.com/nhnent/tui.date-picker) >= 3.0.0 is optional.

[tui-time-picker](https://github.com/nhnent/tui.time-picker) >= 1.0.0 is optional.

You can find all three plugins on github.